# How to call a function based on dynamic range?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to run the PROPAGATEFORMULAE function (see code below) based on a DYNAMIC RANGE (i.e. my number of rows and columns will likely keep changing).

However whenever I run this, the script executes (see [execution transcript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AeEJ.png)) but the PROPAGATEFORMULAE function doesn't seem to be called. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. The function works whenever I set STATIC values to the range, but I'd like to keep them dynamic.

```
function myFunction() {

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Looping columns");
  var lastrow = sh.getLastRow();
  var numrows = lastrow;
  var lastcol = sh.getLastColumn();
  var numcols = lastcol;
  var range = sh.getRange(1,1,numrows,numcols);
  sh.setActiveRange(range);

  return propagateFormulae(range);

}

function getCellFromSheet(row,col,sheet){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[sheet].getRange(row,col);
}

function propagateFormulae(rows, cols, currentSheet){
  for(var i=1;i<=cols;i++){
    for(var j=2;j<=rows;j++){
      if(getCellFromSheet(j,i,currentSheet).getValue().length == 0)
        getCellFromSheet(j-1,i,currentSheet).copyTo(getCellFromSheet(j,i,currentSheet));
      else{
        j=rows;
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this and it worked:

```
function myFunction() {

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Looping columns");
  var lastrow = sh.getLastRow();
  var numrows = lastrow;
  var lastcol = sh.getLastColumn();
  var numcols = lastcol;
  var range = sh.getRange(1,1,numrows,numcols);
  sh.setActiveRange(range);

  return propagateFormulae(numrows, numcols, sh);

}

function propagateFormulae(rows, cols){

  for(var i=1;i<=cols;i++){
    for(var j=2;j<=rows;j++){
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Looping columns");
      if(sh.getRange(j,i).getValue().length == 0)
        sh.getRange(j-1,i).copyTo(sh.getRange(j,i));
      else{
        j=rows;
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing 2 variables that function expected:

```
cols, currentSheet
```

On :

```
return propagateFormulae(range);
```

the Function

```
function propagateFormulae(rows, cols, currentSheet){
```

**Update**
If range object have the variables needed to run the function propagate you need get the value of the object in the function

```
return propagateFormulae(range);
```

Like:

```
function propagateFormulae(range){//expected variable and object

r=$this->range.rows;
c=$this->range.cols;
cs=$this->range.currentSheet;
```

if it not a object you need send all the variables.

Comment: But the RANGE variable is already defining the rows and cols. Isn't it redundant to add rows, cols, and sheet when it's already been defined above by the Range?

Comment: @G.T. no, what he mans is that you defined the fucntion as `function propagateFormulae(rows, cols, currentSheet)` and you are supposed to send a variable for `rows`, for `cols` and for `currentSheet` yet you send a `range` object. That means your function has `rows as range object`, `cols as undefined` and `currentSheet as undefined` so your function does not know what `cols` and `currentSheet` are, yet you use those variables